# plist value changing?

Tags: iphone

i changed pList value through coding.it works fine.but after exiting application,Plist has same value(without changing value)
any help?code is as

```
-(void)ChangePlist:(NSString *)key
{
    NSDictionary *info = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    [info setValue:@"1" forKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you build a project in XCode it will create a new folder and put everything there so any changes made programmatically will only be visible in that folder.

Open a Terminal and go to here:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the changed dictionary back to `Info.plist`. The `NSDictionary` you get is simply an in-memory dictionary. It's not bound to save changes back to `Info.plist` automatically. You can send it the `writeToFile` message with the path to the `Info.plist` file as an argument to save it there.